# How to make application with Visual Studio to use on website

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've been programming very much in C++ and recently I started programming in Visual Studio (C++/Cli and now C#). So, I'm pretty new in VS and my question could maybe sound silly, but...

How can I make some application in Visual Studio and add it on some certain website so that it can be used directly by visitors of that website?

For example: some survey on website and results are being calculated and showed to each visitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use visual studio to develop web application and can program it do anything you would do in your desktop application.

You need to choose a "new website" after starting VS. If you choose everything correctly you will get two files. 
One file will be your design file, that is html. And another file will be your code file.

You place controls on your design page (.aspx page) and by controls I mean all html controls to design your website. And if you want to do some programing with controls, you can use Asp.NET server controls. And in your code page, access their various properties to manipulate data.

However these 2 files are optional. Same task can be acomplished using a single file.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the HTML Editing features. You can find some more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z74w20y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this will allow you to export it in to a existing HTML file (copy and paste) or save it as a new one.

Note: Visual Studio is not a great tool for web site editing, you might want to look at [Coffee Cup](http://www.coffeecup.com/html-editor/) for something light weight.

Comment: Why? Why not an ASP.NET app that doesn't require you to manually edit the HTML?

Comment: I would say personal preference to be honest. ASP.NET App just seams to be over kill for a form no?

Comment: "A survey where results are being calculated" can mean a lot of things. "Write HTML" could (or could not) be a viable answer, no? I'd not suggest Visual Studio as a solution to "write HTML", and the question specifically asks about using VS (and writing an application) to design the web site.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by Write HTML? It seams to contradict your previous content no... Anyway each to their own, just from experience VS outputs fairly "bloated code" and can be a sod to go back and change things. Ideally writing the raw HTML would be best yes

Comment: FTR, I'm not the one that downvoted your answer. Your answer says "use the HTML Editing features", which is "writing HTML" as far as VS goes. It's a crappy visual designer for HTML, IMO (which your second paragraph seems to say as well). So, if VS is not the recommended GUI for HTML development (you're recommending Coffee Cup), and plain HTML doesn't satisfy the "application" portion of the question, I'm not sure this qualifies as an answer to the question asked.

Comment: Fair points. Ill adjust it after I've eaten :)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of resources to get started building web apps with Visual Studio/C# on ASP.net under the the "Learn" link in the top nav. I would suggest starting with MVC.

http://www.asp.net/mvc